# Understand the flow of control when calling a blocking code from non-blocking block?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have the following code

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //var source = BlockingMethod();
            var source2 = NonBlocking();
            source2.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
            //source.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
            private static IObservable<string> BlockingMethod()
            {
              var subject = new ReplaySubject<string>();
              subject.OnNext("a");
              subject.OnNext("b");
              subject.OnCompleted();
              Thread.Sleep(1000);
              return subject;
            }
            private static IObservable<string> NonBlocking()
            {
                return Observable.Create<string>(
                    observable =>
                        {
                            observable.OnNext("c");
                            observable.OnNext("d");
                            observable.OnCompleted();
                            //Thread.Sleep(1000);

                            var source = BlockingMethod();
                            source.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

                            return Disposable.Create(() => Console.WriteLine("Observer has unsubscribed"));
                            //or can return an Action like
                            //return () => Console.WriteLine("Observer has unsubscribed");
                        });
            }
        }
```

which prints

```
c
d
Observer has unsubscribed
a
b
```

Can anyone help me get the flow of the control in the program. I did try reading the Call Stack etc..but could not understand everything.

**EDIT**
Why do i get the above output(which i assume is right) instead of

```
 c 
 d 
 a 
 b 
 Observer has unsubscribed
```

Comment: "I don't understand" is not a question amenable to a clear answer. Ask a more specific question. What precisely do you not understand?

Comment: If you don't like the output you got, please tell us what output do you expect.

Comment: i updated the question with what i thought should be the output and what i got ...i know my initial thought was wrong ...i might be thinking in the old procedural way , i need to get my head around the async way of thinking ...Hope this is not too confusing ..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference in your expected behaviour and the actual behaviour comes from the following line:

```
var subject = new ReplaySubject<string>();
```

By default a `ReplaySubject` uses the `Scheduler.CurrentThread`. It's as if you declared it like so:

```
var subject = new ReplaySubject<string>(Scheduler.CurrentThread);
```

When scheduling using the current thread you get your actions queued up - waiting for the currently executing code to complete *before* it starts. If you want the code to run immediately you need to use `Scheduler.Immediate` like so:

```
var subject = new ReplaySubject<string>(Scheduler.Immediate);
```

Does this explain it sufficiently?

Comment: ok, so this explains almost everything...could i get a few more details regarding when would i possibly use the Scheduler.CurrentThread and Scheduler.Immediate in real us case. Also, how does doing any of this achieve asynchronus beahviour ?

Comment: @ashutoshraina - I would play around with the schedulers to know when to apply a particular scheduler to your needs. Typically though I rarely use `CurrentThread` & `Immediate` - both can easily result in deadlocks. Instead the `ThreadPool` & `NewThread` are more commonly used, and these schedulers are used for asynchronous behaviour.